Scroll up section in React with page load
How can in react typescript  I move the scroll of a section of the page to the first section in page on page load?
I want to scroll a part of the page on page load to the first part
Only the desired section scrolls the entire page

Hi Rashedi! Has this been solved? Do you still need help?

To scroll an Element into view on page load, take a reference to the Element and invoke scrollIntoView() on the Element.
const section = useRef()
<section ref={section}>•••</section>
The example below does this in an effect that will run only once:
useEffect(() => {
    section.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
}, [])
This other example does this on clicking a FloatingButton ReactElement.
const scroll = () => {
    section.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
}
<FloatingButton onClick={scroll} />
